# My Interstitial Ad not working, does not start

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, interstitial

My interstitial ad is not working, Logcat only shows "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet." I followed AdMob instructions but it doesn't start. As an additional note currently my app shows banner ads, no error appears.
This is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
private final var TAG = "MainActivity"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
    adView?.loadAd(adRequest)

    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
        InterstitialAd.load(this, AD_UNIT_ID, adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                Log.d(TAG, adError.toString())
                mInterstitialAd = null
            }

            override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded")
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
            }
        })

        mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
            override fun onAdClicked() {
                // Called when a click is recorded for an ad.
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad was clicked.")
            }

            override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                // Called when ad is dismissed.
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad dismissed fullscreen content.")
                mInterstitialAd = null
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(p0: AdError) {
                // Called when ad fails to show.
                Log.e(TAG, "Ad failed to show fullscreen content.")
                mInterstitialAd = null
            }

            override fun onAdImpression() {
                // Called when an impression is recorded for an ad.
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad recorded an impression.")
            }

            override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                // Called when ad is shown.
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad showed fullscreen content.")
            }
        }
        mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is simply because you have implemented your `if-else` wrongly. You are loading ad only when you have interstitial instance, but as your `if` case is checking wrong condition, you are not going to initialise the instance anyway!

you need to verify the instance just before showing the Ad, not before initialising.

```
if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
  mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
} else {
  Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
}
```

change your code to :

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
    private final var TAG = "MainActivity"
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
        adView?.loadAd(adRequest)
    
            InterstitialAd.load(this, AD_UNIT_ID, adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, adError.toString())
                    mInterstitialAd = null
                }
    
                override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded")
                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
                }
            })
    
            mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
                override fun onAdClicked() {
                    // Called when a click is recorded for an ad.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad was clicked.")
                }
    
                override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Called when ad is dismissed.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad dismissed fullscreen content.")
                    mInterstitialAd = null
                }
    
                override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(p0: AdError) {
                    // Called when ad fails to show.
                    Log.e(TAG, "Ad failed to show fullscreen content.")
                    mInterstitialAd = null
                }
    
                override fun onAdImpression() {
                    // Called when an impression is recorded for an ad.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad recorded an impression.")
                }
    
                override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Called when ad is shown.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad showed fullscreen content.")
                }
            }

        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
        }
    }
    }
```